# Load images dynamically in gridview onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview with image column: Dynamically I am loading id

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="#" onclick="showImages('<%# Eval("id")%>');">Show Image</a>
            <img id="img1" />
         </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and on click I am loading the image

```
    function showImages(id) {                      
        document.getElementById('img1').src = 'Images/' + id + '.jpg';
    }
```

the first row loads when I click the "show image" link but when I click on the second row the image does not load. I checked viewsource and I think reason it is not working is because img id is the same for all rows. How do I make the img id also dynamically.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct. The reason it is not working is because all your img will have same "id". The simple fix is to generate a dynamic id. You can just append that to your image id.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="#" onclick="showImages('img<%# Eval("id")%>');">Show Image</a>
            <img id='img<%# Eval("id")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```